# syntax error? maybe missing something

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Having a syntax error that I can not find I think. e.CmsData is showing error along with e.Message.
Error states: only assignment, call, decrement, and the new object expressions can be used as a statement.

What am I missing?

```
 private static void OnMessageReceived (object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e == null)
                    return;

               if (e.CmsData != null)                             e.CmsData;


                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Message))
                    (e.Message); 
            }
           catch (Exception ex)
            { }
            {
            //    logger.Error(" Exception " + ex);
            //    throw ex;

            } 
        }
```

Comment: What is this: `if (e.CmsData != null)  e.CmsData;` and this `if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Message)) (e.Message)`? That aren't methods so you can't call them without assigning them to a variable.

Comment: `e.CmsData;` is wrong

Comment: Same goes for `e.Message`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I wonder if OP has the expectation that a statement containing just an expression (e.g. `e.CmsData;`) will 'print' the value of the expression. OP, if you are trying to output the value, that's not the way to do it.

Comment: So I guess I should have included more information. I've written a very complex program and I can't post most of it publicly because it contains information for the company I work for in it. I'm not sure how much code stack overflow will let me post

Comment: cmsdata is a function btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
e.CmsData;
```

is not a valid statement, you need to do something with it, like

```
var x = e.CmsData;
```

The same goes for

```
(e.Message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessing a property like you did is invalid

```
e.Cmsdata; // Invalid
```

Properties are just like variables but encapsulated.

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing variables but not doing anything with them.

Try something like this

```
private static void OnMessageReceived (object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e == null)
                    return;

               (e.CmsData != null)
               {
                    var data = e.CmsData;
                    //Do something with "data"
               }

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Message))
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message); 
            }
           catch (Exception ex)
            {
            //    logger.Error(" Exception " + ex);
            //    throw ex;
            } 
        }
```